# PHP JSON array if equals value then echo

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get a specific link for each of my videos from the Vimeo API. I can loop through the results and echo them in a foreach but when I try to access a specific value it still out puts all the results:

```
    // Make Request
    $response = $lib->request('/videos/'.$vurl.'?fields=files', [ ], 'GET');

    // Get Response
    $links = $response['body']['files'];

    foreach ($links as $key => $value) {

        if ($value['width'] = '1920') {

            echo $value['link_secure'];

        } else {

            echo 'no match';

        }
    }
```

How do I access just the result where the $value equals '1920'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use == instead of = here.

```
 if ($value['width'] == 1920) {

        echo $value['link_secure'];

    } else {

        echo 'no match';

    }
```